# Matplotlib functions in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

This is my first python project so I understand that this problem may seem a bit stupid.
I am trying to create a Mandelbrot renderer. I am piecing code together from tutorials and code that I understand to make something.
So basically I have all the maths and the basic functions of the GUI for the renderer but I can't get the matplotlib graph to actually graph inside the tkinter GUI.
The matplolib display part is actually a function that needs `mandelbrot_image(-0.8,-0.7,0,0.1,cmap='hot')` to run. If that code is introduced, the Mandelbrot set is plotted, but in a different matplotlib window.

Here is all my code, I thank you in advance and once again I apologize.

```
   #big thanks and credit goes to to Jean Puget from IBM, SentDex from pythonprogramming.net, and stackoverflow 
   #for teaching me how to use python and inspiring much of this following code


import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,    NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import numpy as np
from numba import jit

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors



#maths and display code derived/inspired from Jean Francois Puget 
#https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/My_Christmas_Gift?lang=en
@jit
def mandelbrot(z,maxiter,horizon,log_horizon):
    c = z
    for n in range(maxiter):
        az = abs(z)
        if az > horizon:
            return n - np.log(np.log(az))/np.log(2) + log_horizon
        z = z*z + c
    return 0

 @jit
 def mandelbrot_set(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,width,height,maxiter):
    horizon = 2.0 ** 40
    log_horizon = np.log(np.log(horizon))/np.log(2)
    r1 = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, width)
    r2 = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, height)
    n3 = np.empty((width,height))
    for i in range(width):
        for j in range(height):
            n3[i,j] = mandelbrot(r1[i] + 1j*r2[j],maxiter,horizon, log_horizon)
    return (r1,r2,n3)


#Display setup
fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
xmin = -2.0
xmax = 0.5
ymin = -1.25
ymax = 1.25
cmap='hot'
# width=20
# height=20
# maxiter=1000
# gamma=0.3

def mandelbrot_image(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,width=10,height=10,\
                 maxiter=1000,cmap='jet',gamma=0.3):
    dpi = 80
    img_width = dpi * width
    img_height = dpi * height
    x,y,z = mandelbrot_set(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,img_width,img_height,maxiter)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(width, height),dpi=72)
    ticks = np.arange(0,img_width,3*dpi)
    x_ticks = xmin + (xmax-xmin)*ticks/img_width
    plt.xticks(ticks, x_ticks)
    y_ticks = ymin + (ymax-ymin)*ticks/img_width
    plt.yticks(ticks, y_ticks)
    ax.set_title(cmap)
    norm = colors.PowerNorm(gamma)
    ax.figshow(z.T,cmap=cmap,origin='lower',norm=norm)


LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)


class base(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, "iconz.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Mandelbrot Renderer")


        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        menubar = tk.Menu(container)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)

        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, MainPage, Donate):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Lets Begin",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainPage))
        button.pack()




class Donate(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Donate", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainPage))
        button1.pack()






class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph Page!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Donate",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Donate))
        button2.pack()


        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)  




app = base()
app.geometry ("800x600")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am apologizing for the horrendously messy code

Comment: Instead of apologizing for the code you could work for yourself on producing a [mcve] of the issue. In the code you show the `mandelbrot_image()`function is never called! It's quite ironic to have a Donate-Button in the code you have tinkered together from other code and asking a question about here. When answering the question, would I get part of the donations???

Comment: I will create that Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the issue asap, thanks for letting me know about that. as for the donations thing, I mean, its more of a joke than an actual function i was going to implement, but if do end up doing it and someone is rich enough to throw some money and a half-baked program than by all means I will give a portion.

Comment: If the solution below answers the question, consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. If it doesn't, you'd probably need to update your question asking more specifically about the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that you create two different figures. The one that lives in the Tk frame is not the one you plot the mandelbrot image to.
So you need to work with the same figure throughout the code.
One option is to let the `mandelbrot_image` create the figure and return it to later be able to supply it to the `FigureCanvas`.
See below for a complete solution.

An additional problem is that matplotlib does not have a `figshow` method. You probably want `imshow()`instead.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import Tkinter as tk

import numpy as np
from numba import jit

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

#maths and display code derived/inspired from Jean Francois Puget 
#https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/My_Christmas_Gift?lang=en
@jit
def mandelbrot(z,maxiter,horizon,log_horizon):
    c = z
    for n in range(maxiter):
        az = abs(z)
        if az > horizon:
            return n - np.log(np.log(az))/np.log(2) + log_horizon
        z = z*z + c
    return 0

@jit
def mandelbrot_set(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,width,height,maxiter):
    horizon = 2.0 ** 40
    log_horizon = np.log(np.log(horizon))/np.log(2)
    r1 = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, width)
    r2 = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, height)
    n3 = np.empty((width,height))
    for i in range(width):
        for j in range(height):
            n3[i,j] = mandelbrot(r1[i] + 1j*r2[j],maxiter,horizon, log_horizon)
    return (r1,r2,n3)


def mandelbrot_image(xmin=-2.,xmax=0.5,ymin=-1.25,ymax=1.25,width=10,height=10,\
                 maxiter=1000,cmap='jet',gamma=0.3):

    dpi = 80
    img_width = dpi * width
    img_height = dpi * height
    x,y,z = mandelbrot_set(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,img_width,img_height,maxiter)

    fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    ticks = np.arange(0,img_width,3*dpi)
    x_ticks = xmin + (xmax-xmin)*ticks/img_width
    plt.xticks(ticks, x_ticks)
    y_ticks = ymin + (ymax-ymin)*ticks/img_width
    plt.yticks(ticks, y_ticks)
    ax.set_title(cmap)
    norm = colors.PowerNorm(gamma)
    ax.imshow(z.T,cmap=cmap,origin='lower',norm=norm)
    return fig

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

class base(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        #tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, "iconz.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Mandelbrot Renderer")


        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        menubar = tk.Menu(container)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)

        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, MainPage):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Lets Begin",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainPage))
        button.pack()


class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph Page!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        # create a figure with the mandelbrot plot inside
        fig = mandelbrot_image()
        # attach this figure to the TK canvas
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)  


app = base()
app.geometry ("800x600")
app.mainloop()
```

*Note: In newer versions of matplotlib you should use `NavigationToolbar2Tk` instead of `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg`.*